# What's the proper method for installing new studs in existing frame?

Tags: studs

FYI - This is similar to a question I asked last week, but is about something more specific.  Expect to see this image yet again in another question I will be asking later today :).

I need to install Genie Clips on the far left and right side of the wall, but there are no studs exposed.  The right side of the wall should be easy since there is a stud right along the edge on the inside.  All I need to do is put a new stud up against it and screw it in.

The left side is a bit different since the next stud is about six inches in.  I am going to need to attach the stud to the top and bottom of the frame.

My questions:

- Right stud: What's the best way to screw the stud into the frame at the top and bottom so that it's sturdy enough to support the new wall I am going to hang on it?
- Left stud: Since I will be able to screw this stud into another stud, how many screws should I use?  Should I put the screws in pairs so that it's two screws side by side all the way down?
- What length and type of screws should I use for both studs?  I am assuming wood screws for this job, but I am not sure about the small details.
- **Edit:** Perhaps there is a sort of metal bracket that I would need to install at the tops and bottoms instead of putting the top and bottom screws in at an angle?

Here's my wall:

[image]

Comment: The "academic" approach would be to leave this as an exercise for your graduate students.

Comment: Fair enough.  I changed the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Right stud: What's the best way to screw the stud into the frame at the top and bottom so that it's sturdy enough to support the new wall I am going to hang on it?

What you're doing here is called "sistering". I personally would use 2 screws each at the top and bottom.  More is unnecessary - after all look at the other studs - nothing holds them in the middle.

> Left stud: Since I will be able to screw this stud into another stud, how many screws should I use? Should I put the screws in pairs so that it's two screws side by side all the way down?

For the left stud you'll need to toenail - that is - install the screws diagonally into the top and bottom plates.  It'll be easier if you pre-drill the holes - install at a 45 deg angle, 2 top 2 bottom again.

> What length and type of screws should I use for both studs? I am assuming wood screws for this job, but I am not sure about the small details.

2x4's are actually 1.5 by 3.5.  So you'll be sistering into a 3" depth, so use 2.5" screws for the sistering, and on the diagonal, use 3.5" screws to cover the length of the hypotenuse and give you good bite w/o over sinking.

Comment: So all I need now are the 3.5" screws.  Thanks for that one.

Comment: I would add at least one screw in the middle of the right stud. You don't want this stud vibrating against the existing stud in a sound deadening project.

Comment: Fair point - and since this is apparently a sound deadening project (based on the other question I just looked up), I'd recommend changing the insulation to something like Quiet-Batt: http://www.soundprooffoam.com/quiet-batt-insulation.html